# Edit rejection caused by low reputation

Tags: support, reputation, rejected-edits

[My edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/16464262) was rejected because

> This edit was intended to address the author of the post and makes no sense as an edit. It should have been written as a comment or an answer.

I've 8 reputation, can't post comments or answers. How should I share my solution?

Please note that I don't want more reputation, I want to share an improved solution. Is not my goal to earn reputation, my goal is to improve an answer so I've edited it. Original answer was starting point of my research so I've considered edition over comment or answer.

Comment: Even unregistered people can post answers. I posted several answers before ever getting an account.

Comment: (Essentially) nobody rejects edits because the suggester doesn't have enough rep. There are only two main reasons you would be unable to post an answer on that question. The first would be if the question was protected, but it isn't. The other is if you're answer-banned, but in that case the site stops you from answering because your answers have mostly been downvoted heavily. Trying to edit your probably-low-quality answers into other people's posts would just make their posts low quality as well, and you shouldn't make them responsible for your ideas anyway.

Comment: Your "edition" puts a _lot_ of words in the original answerer's mouth. If something you edited in is wrong or bad advice (not saying it is), you would rather they take the "credit" for that than you? It will be their answer that gets downvoted, their reputation that gets lost, and potentially their answer that gets deleted. With such a large and total edition, it's more polite to the other user to post your own answer and not attribute so much work and text to them when they very well may not agree with it. Even if you don't want the rep, you shouldn't put words in the other user's mouth.

Comment: As a side note, you _can_ point to their answer with yours. _"To expand on the answer from User..."_ You don't have to claim you didn't start with thiers.

Answer (score 2):

If your intention is to comment on the post, you should [work harder until you get 50 rep](/a/164042/350567) and you'll be able to comment, do not post this as new answer. **Comments posted as answers will get down-voted and deleted *very soon*.** See [FAQ for comments](/q/214173).

If you have something else in mind which is a new answer, post your *answer* instead of editing an existing one.

(From help tip in edit page) **Editing** should:

> - Fix grammatical or spelling errors
> - Clarify meaning without changing it
> - Correct minor mistakes
> - Add related resources or links
> - Always respect the original author

Oh yes. See the last item. You should **not** use editing to add **your own** answers or opinions.

Low reputation isn't a problem to answering unless [you're banned from a site](/a/86998/350567). Even unregistered users are able to post answers! So next time if you have an answer, **post it**.

Comment: Also, some questions are protected and require 10 rep to answer. (The question question OP referenced wasn't protected, however.)

Comment: @Laurel One answer upvote = required rep. Fairly low criterion

Comment: Bad advice. Comments posted as answers will be downvoted, deleted, and just antagonize the user even more.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I didn't tell OP to attempt to post comments before acquiring 50 reps. I'm innocent :(

Comment: The answer starts with a bold and clear message: post a new answer. Maybe if you change the order or at least get rid of that being bold it won't be so bad.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I'm not quite sure how to correctly (precisely) compose my idea. If you know how, can you edit it?

Comment: Done, hope that's fine by you as well.